# is it by Chebychev's inequality?

Tags: pr.probability

Let x be random variables with mean zero and variance 1.
Let n be natural number, t>0, C>0.
Let also $P(x^2\geq n)\geq C/(n^t)$.
Show, if $t\geq4$, then $P(x^2\geq n)\leq C/(n^2)$.

I got so fare, that with $t\geq 4$,
$\frac{C}{n^t}\leq \frac{C}{n^2}\leq P(x^2\geq n)\leq \frac{Ex^4}{n^2}$. But how to find bound on $Ex^4$?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: No, Its in the paper I am reading now, and I cannot get it.
Thank you

Comment: I think this is a consequence of the variance being 1 and the mean being 0. Ignore all the other hypotheses; they're just serving to confuse you.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!!!
David.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [math.se].

Comment: For the right choice of $C$, it is indeed Chebychev's inequality, but I don't see how you can use Chebychev to show $P(x^2 \geq n) \leq C/n^2$ asymptotically for arbitrary $C$.

Comment: @Kaveh: it probably would have been more suitable for math. I'm surprised it didn't get closed for being too elementary, but I suppose questions that are too elementary in the field of mathematics are not too elementary in the field of computer science, and vice versa.

Comment: @ Peter: Sorry, small question. How did you use $t\geq 4$ here?

Comment: @PeterShor sometimes the closing doesn't happen quickly enough :)

Comment: @David: You do not need $t\geq 4$ in the proof. See my comment above---it's a completely unnecessary hypothesis. All you need is variance 1 and mean 0. I'm also assuming that what you need is that $\forall C \,\exists n_0$ such that $P(x^2 \geq n) \leq C/n^2$ for $n \geq n_0$. If I've misinterpreted the question, you should ask the correct question on [math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), where it would be more suitable.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose to the contrary that
$$ P(x^2 \geq n_i) \geq C/n_i^2 $$ for some infinite sequence $n_1$, $n_2$, $\ldots$, $n_i$, $\ldots$, with $P(x^2 > n_i) > 2P(x^2 > n_{i+1})$. Then we have $$ Var(x) = \int_{x=0}^\infty x^2 d \mu.$$
But now, let's set $n_0 = 0$ and break this integral up into 
$$ Var(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \int_{n_j}^{n_{j+1}}x^2 d \mu.$$
We have$$ \int_{n_j}^{n_{j+1}} x^2 d\mu \geq n_j^2 \int_{n_j}^{n_{j+1}} d\mu = n_j^2(P(x\geq n_j)-P(x \geq n_{j+1})) \geq C/2.$$
This shows that the integral diverges, contradicting the variance being 1.